# Ember serialize embedded record with custom key

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've a model with `store` attribute in it. Unfortunately `store` is a reserved word in ember-data so I had to change its name to `authStore`. I can't change backend API to use new attribute name, so I've created a new serializer just for this model.

Model is:

```
App.Auth = DS.Model.extend({
  status: DS.attr("string"),
  authStore: DS.belongsTo("store"),
});
```

If I use following serializer, json sent to server contains the right `store` key

```
App.AuthSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    authStore: 'store',
  }
});
```

But I also need to specify `embedded: 'always'` for `authStore` attribute and so I've update the serializer to

```
App.AuthSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    authStore: {key: 'store', embedded: 'always'}
  }
});
```

This way `key` attribute is ignored and even if authStore is embedded when json is sent to server, `key` attribute is ignored and it has key `authStore` instead of `store`.
How can I make both `key` and `embedded` attributes work togheter?

I'm using ember-cli 0.2.7 and ember-data 1.0.0-beta.18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why key is being overridden, but in the meantime, I think in your serializer you can do something like this:

```
App.AuthSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    authStore: {embedded: 'always'}
  },

  normalize: function(typeClass, hash) {
    hash.authStore = hash.store;
    delete hash.store;
    return this._super(typeClass, hash)
  },

  serialize: function(snapshot, options) {
    var json = this._super(snapshot, options);
    json.store = json.authStore;
    delete json.authStore;
    return json;
  }
});
```

Doesn't seem to be any easy to find docs on something I'm sure other people have run in to.

Answer (score 1):

`embedded: 'always'` is the same as writing `serialize: 'records', deserialize: 'records'`, where `records` can also be `ids`, `false`, or their singular if relationship is a belongsTo.

As such, try:

```
App.AuthSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    authStore: {key: 'store', serialize: 'records', deserialize: 'records'}
  }
});
```

I have managed to make a model called store by wrapping it in quotes. Here is a copy from the Operators Serializer, where Operators has a hasMany relationship with "store":

```
attrs: {
    "stores" : { deserialize: 'records', serialize: 'ids' }
}
```